# Cannot use npm to-uri package

Tags: node.js, cyrillic

trying to use https://www.npmjs.org/package/to-uri, but it says toURI function is not defined, how do I make it global or call it from package directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a weird module, but this seems to work:

```
String.prototype.toURI = require('to-uri');
...
var text = 'Тест: Проверим текст на русском языке';
console.log(text.toURI());
```

This produces the following:

```
'test-proverim-text-na-russkom-yazyke'
```

Comment: actually I had a typo at first, used it via .call(text) then